# ArrayList fills not correctly while parsing with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, list, retrofit, synchronous

I have an array of model "Event". There's a model "Place" which can be null. So, I try to parse JSON with place id and if it is null, add "null" to ArrayList. While I'm debugging manually a for loop, ArrayList is correct at the output, but if I'm not debugging the for loop, result is not correct at all.

Left is correct.

[image: Correct] [image: Incorrect]

My code snippet:

```
private void handleResponse(ResponseData responseData) {

    ArrayList<Event> events = responseData.getEvents();
    PlaceApiService placeApiService = RetrofitClient.getPlaceApiService();
    int eventsSize = events.size();

    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < eventsSize; i++) {
        Place place = responseData.getEvents().get(i).getPlace();
        if (place != null) {
            Call<PlaceDetail> call = placeApiService.getPlaceJson(place.getId());

            Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    Response<PlaceDetail> response = call.execute();
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        placeDetails.add(response.body());
                    } else {
                        Log.d("myLog", String.valueOf(response.message()));
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            thread.start();
            threads.add(thread);
        } else {
            placeDetails.add(null);
        }
    }

    for (Thread t : threads) {
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    ArrayList<PlaceDetail> details = new ArrayList<>(placeDetails);
    getViewState().showProgress(false);
    getViewState().finishSwipeRefresh();
    getViewState().showData(responseData.getEvents(), details);
}
```

Comment: Rather than calling `execute` in a thread, why not call `enqueue` and let Retrofit handle the threading for you?  You can use a CountDownLatch to wait for the results.

Comment: @nasch because I didn't know about CountDownLatch before your advice :) Thank you for it

Comment: You're quite welcome. It's a great tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two flaw:

1. Use non-threadsafe (`List`) container without synchronization
2. Access the list while your retrofit thread might be not returned.

To solve (1), I suggest you use thread-safe container like `Vector` then you can convert it to `List` after done.

To solve (2), you can use `Thread.join()` to ensure all API call complete before going next.

One more side note, you don't want to call `Thread.join()` on your `for` loop. It will block the loop. Instead, just `start()` and store the thread handlers to array, then after the `for` loop, you loop over the thread handler and call `join()`:

```
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < eventsSize; i++) {
    if (...) {
        Thread t = new Thread()...;
        t.start(); // Don't call join() after start() here
        threads.add(t);
    } else {
       ...
    }
}

// Instead call join here:

for (Thread t : threads) {
   t.join(); // Need try catch
}
.. bla bla..
```

Comment: omg, how could I forget about join()? You saved my time! But one more question. What should I use instead of Thread for this type of connections? Because I know that Thread are unbelieveable slowly...

Comment: Thread does not slow. It's startup time of thread that make you feel it slow. To solve that, you will want to set up a ThreadPoolExecutor (which will initialize and maintain of reusable threads pool). You still experiment the slow start when pool startup the threads, but after that you don't have problem with thread-start time anymore.

Comment: One more side note, you don't want to call `Thread.join()` on your `for` loop. It will block the loop, instead, just `start()` and store the thread handlers to array, then after the `for` loop, you loop over the thread handler and call `join()` as my edited answer

Comment: So, as I understood, you can recommend me a Thread for this type of job and I shouldn't see at any other solutions?

Comment: Yes. Everything come to `Thread`. You can minimize the thread-start time by using ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: Tried now your solution at edited post code and it is not working (result exactly as at my second screen).

Comment: Post your current code. If you do everything as I suggested, it's should run ok

Comment: Do you make `placeDetails` as a `Vector`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171425/discussion-between-eamax-and-mnh-quyt-nguyn).